# Magento 2: How to change Custom order number

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I'm trying to change `sales_order` **entity_id**, but can't. In my client system having 65451 orders, they want to change order number like 95651 for some reason. We can change `sales_order` increment_id, but is there possibility to change `sales_order` **entity_id**?

please suggest us if we can?

Comment: Please check the [link](https://bsscommerce.com/blog/complete-tutorial-guide-change-order-number-magento-2/). It will have all possible solution which you want to change in order number. Thanks and Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change table auto-increment number for sales(sales_order, sales_order_grid) table.

Ex:

```
ALTER TABLE sales_order AUTO_INCREMENT= 65451;
```

Comment: If you want that order id would be equal to increment id then you must change AUTO_INREMENT value to the same in both tables: `sales_order`, `sequence_order_1`